# replace the table data with the selected data(javascript)

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, ecmascript-6, fetch

javascript beginner here, trying to code and learn.

I have a table filled with data (fetch from url) and that data is

```
{
  "france": "paris",
  "finland": "helsinki",
  "sweden": "stockholm",
  "tajikistan": "dushanbe",
  "uzbekistan ": "toshkent",
  "china": "peking",
  "dole": {
    "Key": "fhd699f"
  }
}
```

and under the table I have a select box (the data of it also fetched from url) its data is this

```
[
{"nimi": "tili","id": "48385","somewhere": "nassau","somewhere2": "bamako","somewhere3": "rabat","somewhere4": "baku"},
{"nimi": "tili","id": "789642","somewhere": "windhoek","somewhere2": "podgorica","somewhere3": "niamey","somewhere4": "islamabad"}
]
```

i want to replace the table data with the selected data ( i mean everything) even table's `<th>` also, for example table's `<th>` is 'france' and value is 'paris' but after replace table's `<th>` should be 'nimi' and value 'tili' according to select box data.
here is my code (as you can see 'tajikistan','uzbekistan','china' for some reason not going to their places in table):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    </style>
 
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">

<table class="table  "> 
  <thead> 
    <tr>
   <th class="table-success">france</th>
      <th class="table-success">finland</th>
      <th class="table-success">sweden</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody id="tiedot">  
  </tbody>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="table-success">tajikistan</th> 
      <th class="table-success">uzbekistan</th>
      <th class="table-success">china</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
 <tbody id="tiedot2">  
  </tbody>

</table>

<select id="valittu" name="name"></select>

</div>

<script>
    fetch(
            "https://tdejdjd***",
            {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                "x-api-key": "i****y"
              }
            }
          )
  .then((res) => {
  res
    .json()
    .then((data) => {
      tableupdating(data, ['france','finland','sweden','tajikistan','uzbekistan','china']);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("ERROR: " + err);
});
});
   
function tableupdating(data, values) {
  const totable = document.getElementById("tiedot");
  const totable2 = document.getElementById("tiedot2");
  
  totable.innerHTML = "";
  totable2.innerHTML = "";
  
  var komb = "";
  var komb2 = "";
  komb += "<tr>";
  komb2 += "<tr>";

  values.forEach(value => {
      komb += "<td>" + data[value] + "</td>";
  })
    values.forEach(value => {
      komb2 += "<td>" + data[value] + "</td>";
  })
  totable.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", komb);
  totable2.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", komb2);
}
let dataArray;
    fetch(
            "https://tdejdjd***",
            {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                "x-api-key": "i****y"
              }
            }
          )
  .then((res) => {
  res.json().then((data) => {
    dataArray = data;
    updateSelect(data, ['nimi','id']);
  });
});
function updateSelect(data, values) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var Valittu = document.getElementById("valittu");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    values.forEach(value => {
        option.textContent += data[i][value] + ' '
    })
    Valittu.appendChild(option);
  }
}
   
document.getElementById("valittu").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  const chosenID = event.target.value.split(" ")[1];

  const chosenData = dataArray.filter((data) => data.id === chosenID)[0];

  tableupdating(chosenData, ['nimi', 'id', 'somewhere','somewhere2','somewhere3','somewhere4']);
});
   
   
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

as spoken in chat, here is new code, it is working but for some reason these three are in same line and not on their places : `komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.tajikistan+"</td>";
        komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.uzbekistan+"</td>";
        komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.china+"</td></tr>";`

code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    </style>
 
</head>
<body onload="fillTheBox();">
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-success">france</th>
                    <th class="table-success">finland</th>
                    <th class="table-success">sweden</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tiedot">
            </tbody>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-success">tajikistan</th>
                    <th class="table-success">uzbekistan</th>
                    <th class="table-success">china</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <select id="valittu" name="name" onchange="changed()"></select>
    </div>

    <script>
 fetch("https://qj",
              {
              method: "GET",
              headers: {
                 "x-api-key": ""
              }
            }
          ).then(res =>{ 
    res.json().then(tiedot => {
        console.log(tiedot);
        var komb  ="";
      


        komb  +="<tr>";
        komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.france+"</td>";
        komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.finland+"</td>";
        komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.sweden+"</td>";
  komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.tajikistan+"</td>";
     komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.uzbekistan+"</td>";
  komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.china+"</td></tr>";

        document.getElementById("tiedot").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", komb );
 


    }
  )
})
        var dataArray = [
            { "nimi": "tili", "id": "48385", "somewhere": "nassau", "somewhere2": "bamako", "somewhere3": "rabat", "somewhere4": "baku" },
            { "nimi": "tili", "id": "789642", "somewhere": "windhoek", "somewhere2": "podgorica", "somewhere3": "niamey", "somewhere4": "islamabad" }
        ]
        function fillTheBox() {
            var selectBox = document.getElementById("valittu");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = dataArray[0];
            option.text = dataArray[0].nimi+' '+dataArray[0].id;
            selectBox.add(option);
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.value = dataArray[1];
            option1.text = dataArray[1].id;
            selectBox.add(option1);
        }
        function changed() {
            var e = document.getElementById("valittu");
            var selectedObjectID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            chosenData = dataArray.filter((data) => data.id === selectedObjectID)[0];
            var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
            myTable.innerHTML = "";
            generateTable(myTable, chosenData);
        }
    function generateTable(table, data) {
        let row1 = table.insertRow();
        row1.className = "table-success";
        let row2 = table.insertRow();
   
        let row3 = table.insertRow();
        row3.className = "table-success";
        let row4 = table.insertRow();
 
        var counter = 1;
        for (key in data) {
            if (counter<=3) {
                let cell = row1.insertCell();
                let text = document.createTextNode(key);
                cell.appendChild(text);
                let cell2 = row2.insertCell();
                let text2 = document.createTextNode(data[key]);
                cell2.appendChild(text2);
            } else {
                let cell = row3.insertCell();
                let text = document.createTextNode(key);
                cell.appendChild(text);
                let cell2 = row4.insertCell();
                let text2 = document.createTextNode(data[key]);
                cell2.appendChild(text2);
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a basic demo to show the logic. Firs of all give an `id` to your table. And create a `onChange` event for your select box. In your event function edit your table content with `innerHTML` property. Just focus on `change()` and `generateTable()` functions in my code

```
<body onload="fillTheBox();">
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table" id="myTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-success">france</th>
                    <th class="table-success">finland</th>
                    <th class="table-success">sweden</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tiedot">
            </tbody>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="table-success">tajikistan</th>
                    <th class="table-success">uzbekistan</th>
                    <th class="table-success">china</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        <select id="valittu" name="name" onchange="changed()"></select>
    </div>

    <script>
        var dataArray = [
            { "nimi": "tili", "id": "48385", "somewhere": "nassau", "somewhere2": "bamako", "somewhere3": "rabat", "somewhere4": "baku" },
            { "nimi": "tili", "id": "789642", "somewhere": "windhoek", "somewhere2": "podgorica", "somewhere3": "niamey", "somewhere4": "islamabad" }
        ]
        function fillTheBox() {
            var selectBox = document.getElementById("valittu");
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = dataArray[0];
            option.text = dataArray[0].id;
            selectBox.add(option);
            var option1 = document.createElement("option");
            option1.value = dataArray[1];
            option1.text = dataArray[1].id;
            selectBox.add(option1);
        }
        function changed() {
            var e = document.getElementById("valittu");
            var selectedObjectID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            chosenData = dataArray.filter((data) => data.id === selectedObjectID)[0];
            var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
            myTable.innerHTML = "";
            generateTable(myTable, chosenData);
        }
    function generateTable(table, data) {
        let row1 = table.insertRow();
        row1.className = "table-success";
        let row2 = table.insertRow();
        row2.className = "table-success";
        let row3 = table.insertRow();
        row3.className = "table-success";
        let row4 = table.insertRow();
        row4.className = "table-success";
        var counter = 1;
        for (key in data) {
            if (counter<=3) {
                let cell = row1.insertCell();
                let text = document.createTextNode(key);
                cell.appendChild(text);
                let cell2 = row2.insertCell();
                let text2 = document.createTextNode(data[key]);
                cell2.appendChild(text2);
            } else {
                let cell = row3.insertCell();
                let text = document.createTextNode(key);
                cell.appendChild(text);
                let cell2 = row4.insertCell();
                let text2 = document.createTextNode(data[key]);
                cell2.appendChild(text2);
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
To separate the fields mentioned in question add a `<tr>` element between them.

```
    komb  +="<tr>";
    komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.france+"</td>";
    komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.finland+"</td>";
    komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.sweden+"</td>";
    komb  +="</tr><tr>";
    komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.tajikistan+"</td>";
    komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.uzbekistan+"</td>";
    komb  += "<td>"+tiedot.china+"</td></tr>";
```

Comment: i mean it should be same table(bootstrap should stay) but just replace data, and your replaced data everything goes on the same line (same problem mine has), three in one row and another three in second row, got what i mean ?

Comment: currently in table there is : france and under it paris and so on but in replaced version there should be 'nimi' and under it 'tili'

Comment: I edited answer. my maybe this what you looking for

Comment: you are near to what i want, could you come to chat i can draw and send then you get my idea

Comment: you want keys in header row and values in another row right?

Comment: I think we agreed. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211238/discussion-between-walee-and-kerim).